# passing value down the pipe in Scala parser combinator

Tags: scala, parsing

I have the following rules (many others obmitted for clarity):

```
def bindRg: Parser[Cmd] = "bind-roaming-group" ~> name ~ bindRgBody(????) <~ 
    exit  ^^ { case name~body => new BindRoamingGroupCmd(name, body)}

def bindRgBody(name: String) = // ...

def name: Parser[String] = """\S+""".r
```

I want to pass the string value of "name" into bindRgBody(????) but not sure what to put in for '????'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` on the parser `"bind-roaming-group" ~> name`:

```
def bindRg: Parser[Cmd] = ("bind-roaming-group" ~> name) flatMap (n => bindRgBody(n) <~ exit ^^ (b => new BindRoamingGroupCmd(n, b)))
```

or

```
def bindRg: Parser[Cmd] = ("bind-roaming-group" ~> name) >> (n => bindRgBody(n) <~ exit ^^ (new BindRoamingGroupCmd(n, _)))
```

if you want to shorten it a bit.

Comment: very short and sweet answer!